# GeoChart : addListener :ERROR Error: Invalid column index null. Should be an integer in the range [0-1]

Tags: typescript, google-visualization

I am trying to get country name of the clicked country from Google GeoChart but I am getting the mentioned error by using addListner.

stack Blitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-advanced?embed=1&file=src/app/home/home.component.ts&hideExplorer=1&hideNavigation=1

Also, is it possible to display the color axis bar with region name as for the selected color?

Answer (score 0):

GeoChart only returns the row index, and null for the column

use column 0 (zero), it will always be the column for country name

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
    ['Germany', 200],
    ['United States', 300],
    ['Brazil', 400],
    ['Canada', 500],
    ['France', 600],
    ['RU', 700]
  ]);

  var options = {};

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

  function selectHandler() {
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection();
    if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
      console.log(data.getValue(selectedItem[0].row, 0));
    }
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I get the same error can  you show it in the stackblitz snippet?

Comment: the only error i see is _incompatible data table: Error: Unknown address type.×_ -- not sure where this is coming from...

Comment: I tried the same using angular-google-charts and get the same error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-advanced?embed=1&file=src/app/single-country/single-country.component.ts&hideExplorer=1&hideNavigation=1